# Unable to start chrome process in .NET C# application

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am getting error on Selenium and unable to start chrome process. I am using Google Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (64-bit) and Selenium Web Driver 3.141.0

[image]

[image]

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
 {
    BinaryLocation = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
 };
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("incognito");
    
   using (ChromeDriver window = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions))
    {
      try
        {
         log.Debug("Chrome window instantiated");
```

Comment: The HResult is -2146233088. Convert that to hex (the more normal representation), and it's 0x80131500. That's not one of the [standard values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8), but a quick google suggests it's probably a result of antivirus software intercepting the attempt to start the process. Check your AV logs, and try disabling it

Answer (score 0):

Did you install chromedriver too? If you haven't already: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: I download and paste in project directory folder. I have not did anything else other than than!